# AngularJS/Javascript assigning a key to a variable syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Since i put a unique key in my Local Storage, I am not so sure if i have to reference it in the view

//Model

```
$localStorage['uniqueKey'] =[{id:1, name:"foo"}, {id:2, name:"bar"}]
```

// Controller

```
$scope.users = $localStorage['uniqueKey'];
```

//View --> do I have to refer to the unique Key?? or this is okay?????????

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users">
{{user.name}}
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.users = $localStorage.['uniqueKey']; 
                            ^^ syntax error: dot should not be here

//This should be:

$scope.users = $localStorage['uniqueKey'];
//or
$scope.users = $localStorage.uniqueKey;
//or
$scope.users = $localStorage.get("uniqueKey");
```

**Correct usage**. Storing objects in [localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage):

```
$localStorage.uniqueKey = angular.toJson([{id:1, name:"foo"}, {id:2, name:"bar"}]);

$scope.users = angular.fromJson($localStorage.uniqueKey);
```

You can use the [angular.toJson()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson) to convert an object to a string, and [angular.fromJson](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson) to reverse it. **[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/sW16Jy8PXouqHGOkP1w2?p=preview)**

Comment: yeah in the view do i have to refer to he Unique Key

Comment: So in the view i can simply do {{user.name}} without having to refer to the 'uniqueKey'????

Comment: You not can storing objects into localStorage, here just are stored strings. [look](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2010948/1074519) this answer

Comment: I don't think you got the question... so let's say i did this 
$scope.users = $localStorage['uniqueKey'];

in my view.... DO I HAVE TO REFERENCE the 'uniqueKey'??

<li ng-repeat="user in users">
{{user.name}}
</li>

Comment: if you work with `localStorage` you must first convert the object to a string and then reverse it. **[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/sW16Jy8PXouqHGOkP1w2?p=preview)**

Comment: Let's say i did convert it to string does the view syntax make sense